# jQuery works in jsfiddle but not in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been working on a screen greyout script in jQuery. It works in the link below on my jsFiddle, but the code below from my WordPress plugin does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/jblevins1991/8ts25q2v/1/

PHP code to include javascript:

```
function myScripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myScript', plugins_url('myPlugin/JS/myScript.js'), array('jquery'), true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myScripts');
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<img id="something" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png" />
```

The jquery from myScript.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#something').click(function() {
        $('#box').show();
        $('#box').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your javascript even being rendered?  Check your html source first.

Comment: Debug your code. `console.log($('#something'));` from inside the document ready. Does it find an element? Add a line inside of the click, is it called? Does it find box? Also weird you show and do fadeTo. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: All other normal javascript code is working. It is literally everything related to jquery. I have tried checking to see if jquery is loading on the page and it is in the header. I also used jslint to make sure that it was valid jquery code.

Comment: I highly doubt that it is my code. I think it's more on the wordpress side of things. I say that because it works in a normal html page, jsfiddle, but not wordpress.

Comment: Is jQuery included before or after myScript?

Comment: I'd have to say the easiest solution is to not use WordPress :P

Comment: jQuery is included before. The array('jquery') parameter is the dependancy on jquery. Which means WordPress will check if jquery has been loaded by a previous script and if it has not it will load it before loading myScript. No Nicholas, it is not. I would have to write everything else again in another format. If you do not have anything helpful to add do not post. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the forth parameter of wp_enqueue_script should be a string, null or false. Not sure why you use true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following JavaScript code instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#something').click(function(){
        $('#box').show();
        $('#box').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    });
});
```

It's basically wrapping your code in a No Conflict wrapper because using $() might return undefined otherwise.

Comment: You sir are just wonderful! Thank you for the solution.

Comment: To put a sharper point on this answer: WordPress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode.  You *can not* access jQuery via `$` without using a no-conflict-safe document ready.  An alternate shorthand no-conflict-safe jQuery document ready is simply `jQuery(function($) { // .. $ is safe in here ... });`